# Related rates problem with tower and plane

Tags: calculus

I am currently stuck on the following related rates problem:

> An aircraft flying at $4000$ meters and at a ground speed of $450$ km/h passes over the control tower and heads east. At the beacon checkpoint $20$ minutes later, it turns to head northeast. At what rate is it now receding from the control tower?

I have been stuck on this problem for a while, and I can't seem to get the answer the textbook got ($318$ km/h). Here is what I understand/tried so far:

- I feel like it is unnecessary to use a non-right angle triangle since we want the instantaneous rate of change right when the aircraft begins to move northeast.
- In this case, we use the Pythagorean theorem to obtain $$x^2 + 4^2 = z^2$$ where $x$ represents the base of the triangle and $z$ is the separation between the aircraft and the control tower.
- Differentiating and substituting gives us $$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{x}{z} \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x}{\sqrt[]{x^2 + 4^2}} \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x}{\sqrt[]{x^2 + 16}} \frac{dx}{dt}$$
- If $x=150km$ (the horizontal distance travelled in $20$ minutes), this gives me $449.84$ km/h.

I would appreciate any insight or comments on my approach. I feel like I am close. But, I need another head or two to help me out.

Answer (score 2):

If we let $z$ be up and $x$ be east the vector from the tower to the plane is $(150,0,4)$ and the velocity of the plane is $(\frac {450}{\sqrt 2},\frac {450}{\sqrt 2},0)$  You are supposed to project the velocity vector on the vector from the tower to the plane.  If the altitude were zero, the projection would just be $\frac {450}{\sqrt 2} \approx 318.198$.  Your result should be just a bit less.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it necessary to do this in a 3-dimensional setting? I am having a bit of trouble trying to translate this back to 2-dimensional setting using single-variable functions. If it's okay with you, could you please help explain further?

Comment: Also, for the coordinate (150, 0, 4), wouldn't it make sense to say (150, 4, 0) instead?

Comment: I defined my coordinates with $z$ vertical, so that is why I put the $4$ in the last slot.  What is important is that the $4$ is not along one of the directions of the velocity.  Do you understand my 2D case with zero altitude?

Comment: I think this makes sense now. You want to project (150, 0, 4) onto the separation vector. I just need to figure out how to translate this using calculus jargon.

Comment: No, we want to project the velocity vector onto $(150,0,4)$, which is the separation vector.  The part of the velocity transverse to the separation is not increasing the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(0,0)$ be the Cartesian coordinates of the tower. Let $t = 0$ hours be the moment when the plane turns $45^\circ$ portwards. Hence, the coordinates (in kilometers) of the airplane at $t$ are given by

$$\begin{array}{rl} x (t) &= 150 + 450 \left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right) t\\ y (t) &= 450 \left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right) t\end{array}$$

In **cylindrical** coordinates,

$$r (t) := \sqrt{x^2(t) + y^2(t)} = \cdots = 150 \sqrt{9 t^2 + 3 \sqrt 2 t + 1}$$

and, thus,

$$\dot r (0) = 450 \left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right) \approx 318 \,\rm{km} \cdot\rm{h}^{-1}$$

---

#### Addendum

In **spherical** coordinates,

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = Symbol('t')
>>> x = 150 + 450*sqrt(0.5)*t
>>> y = 450*sqrt(0.5)*t
>>> z = 4
>>> rho = sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
>>> diff(rho,t)
(202500.0*t + 47729.707730092)/sqrt(101250.0*t**2 + (318.198051533946*t + 150)**2 + 16)
>>> diff(rho,t).subs(t,0)
4.23962584207603*sqrt(5629)
>>> float(4.23962584207603*sqrt(5629))
318.0849747530005
```

Comment: I think you are supposed to consider the $4$ km altitude.  It doesn't make much change, but you should consider it.

Comment: $$\cos \left( \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{4}{150}\right)\right) = 0.999657 \approx 1$$ I think the error is negligible. Air traffic controllers may also use cylindrical coordinates, namely, (range, azimuth, altitude).

Comment: I agree it is small, but we were given the $4$ km altitude and shouldn't ignore it.

Comment: I appended an addendum on that. Speed drops 113 meters per hour.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$$ 450 [ (1 + 1/\sqrt 2) i  + (1/\sqrt 2) j ]$$

when integrating add initial value altitude $z$ constant value along $k$ vector.